# Menu with submenu

Tags: php, mysql

```
$arrayCategories = array();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY sort ASC");
$stmt->execute();

foreach($stmt as $item){
    $arrayCategories[$item['id']] = array("parent_id" => $item['parent_id'], "name" => $item['name']);
}

buildMenu($arrayCategories, 0, 1);

function buildMenu($array, $parent, $level){
    foreach ($array as $categoryId => $category){
        if($parent == $category['parent_id']){
        if($level == 1){
            echo '<a href="/category/' . $categoryId . '">' . $category['name'] . ' (' . $categoryId . ')</a>';
            echo '<br>';                
        }elseif($level == 2){
            echo '<a href="/category/' . $categoryId . '">--' . $category['name'] . ' (' . $categoryId . ')</a>';
            echo '<br>';            
        }elseif($level == 3){
            echo '<a href="/category/' . $categoryId . '">----' . $category['name'] . ' (' . $categoryId . ')</a>';
            echo '<br>';                
        }

        $nextlevel = $level + 1;
        buildMenu($array, $categoryId, $nextlevel);
    }
}
}
```

DATABASE

```
id  name                    parent_id   sort
1   category 1              0           0
2   category 2              0           0
3   category 3              0           0
4   sub category 1          1           0
5   sub category 2          1           0
6   sub category 1          3           0
7   sub category 2          3           0
8   sub sub category 1      7           0
9   sub sub category 2  7           0
```

RESULT

```
category 1 
--sub category 1 
--sub category 2 
category 2 
category 3 
--sub category 1 
--sub category 2 
----sub sub category 1 
----sub sub category 2
```

I want it to only expand up until the selected category and not expand the entire menu

So if I choose sub sub category 2 from sub category 2 from category 3 I dont want sub category 1 and sub category 2 from category 1 to show.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: How do you define the selected category? is it stored in a variable?

Comment: Yes the selected category is stored in a variable. I am just not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What's the name of the variable? And what is an example value it would have?

Comment: Use something like /category/sub1/sub2 for generate URL and you have all sub levels in your URL for parsing to redirect right category. If you do not use rewrite for URL use variables in URL like GET (for example category&l1=1&l2=2)

Comment: OR use DB id of each menu item, and you got unique ID for URL parameter, and if you click and redirect to this category, you only search actual id and regenerate menu, and highlight actual position in your menu

Answer (score 0):

Given that you probably have a small number of subcategory levels (ie: 3, not thousands), the simplest solution would probably be to execute a query for every "parent", to get its list of children.
Because you're using a prepared statement, there will be less burden on your db engine as far as generating a query plan.

Since you linearly output the menu (ie you're not nesting them inside `<ul>`s and whatnot, what we'll do is build an "output" array that contains each menu item, but we'll build it backwards. We'll start at your $chosencat, and work our way upwards through the parents. Afterwards, we'll reverse the array and output the HTML. Note that this means that even your SQL's `ORDER` has to be in desc order.

```
// Define the chosen category
$chosencat = 9;

// Prepare your SQL statement to find all the children of a particular parent_id
$categorySQL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM categories WHERE parent_id=? ORDER BY sort DESC"); 

// Prepare your SQL statement to find the parent of the parent that is being iterated over
$parentSQL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT parent_id FROM categories WHERE id=?"); 


// Determine the parent of the chosen category, so that we can display all the children.
$parentSQL->execute(array($chosencat));
$currentParent = $parentSQL['parent_id'];
$lastParent = $chosencat;


// Loop through the categories
$arrayCategories = array();
$tempCategory = array();
do
{
    // Get the children of the current parent
    $categorySQL->execute(array($currentParent));

    // Save all the children from the last iteration, to be applied to the child in this iteration
    $lastChildren = $arrayCategories;

    // Reset $arrayCategories (since we want to keep "one-level-up"ing)
    $arrayCategories = array();

    // Now add the children of the current parent to the newly "one-level-up'ed array"
    foreach($categorySQL as $item)
    {
        // Build a list of the current category's children
        $tempCategory = array("parent_id" => $item['parent_id'], "name" => $item['name'], "children" => array());

        if ($item['id'] == $lastParent)
        {$tempCategory["children"] = $lastChildren;}

        // Apply it to the main $arrayCategories
        $arrayCategories[] = $tempCategory;
    }

    // Now get the next parent to iterate over:
    $lastParent = $currentParent;
    $parentSQL->execute(array($currentParent));
    $currentParent = $parentSQL['parent_id'];
}
while ($currentParent != 0); // Is there still a parent to iterate over?


// Now we can build a simple output array, based on the $arrayCategories just created
$menu_array = buildMenu($arrayCategories, 0);

// And output the menu
print implode("<br>\n", $menu_array);


// Function to build the menu
function buildMenu($array, $level)
{
    $output = array();
    foreach ($array as $categoryId => $category)
    {
        if (count($category['children']) > 0) // Does this have children?
        {
            // Prepend all the children before the parent.
            // Note that we are merging the output of buildMenu before the current $output.
            $output = array_merge(buildMenu($category['children'], ($level+1)), $output);
        }

        // The HTML for the menu item to output
        $output[] = '<a href="/category/' . $categoryId . '">' . str_repeat("-", $level) . $category['name'] . ' (' . $categoryId . ')</a>';
    }

    // Now reverse the $output array.
    // Currently $output has the top-most element listed last, but now we want it listed first.
    return array_reverse($output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the effort to help me! I am still learning PDO (and PHP) and this will really help me.

However I am encountering an error on this line :
$parentSQL->execute(array($chosencat));

Error:
Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in C:\xampp2\htdocs\index.php:48 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp2\htdocs\index.php
on line
48